# Top bar in GNOME hides information

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, interface

As you can see in my screenshot, the width of the top bar is sufficient to fit in all the information: texts, icons and graphs. Yet it seems to be implied that the top bar should not go beyond a certain width to accommodate these indicators.

How can this issue be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the top bar items encroaching on the clock?  You might try the gnome extension ["Frippery Clock Move"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I hid the clock with another Gnome extension. Unfortunately the "Flippery Clock Move" extension didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Some of them are.

Comment: @UnKNOWn https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/ is one of them. Thanks.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Do you know how to fix this?